# How to rollback automatically if script having error in Oracle sql plus

Tags: oracle, unix, plsql

I need to execute the multiple script having one master sql file. Whenever I used to execute the master calling script named as `calling_test.sql` if anything error comes need to be rollbacked.

```
sqlplus USERNAME/PWD@SIR_NAME;
@@calling_test.sql
```

here is content of `calling_test.sql` script.

```
SET echo ON; 
SET define ON; 
SET scan ON; 
define PATH =/krishna/test 
define AB_SCHEMA=AIM 
spool Test_incremental.log 
SET define ON; 
@@&&PATH/AUG/2019-08-28/test1.sql
SET define ON; 
@@&&PATH/AUG/2019-08-29/test2.sql 
SET define ON; 
@@&&PATH /AUG/2019-08-30/test3.sql 
SET define ON;
```

Comment: For future reference please **edit your question** to provide further details or other improvements. In particular code is hard to read in a comment due to the poor layout and lack of formatting.

Answer (score 1):

The scrip should contain something like this:

```
whenever sqlerror exit rollback
```

Example:

```
SQL> create table test (col number);

Table created.

SQL>
```

SQL script (named `p.sql`)

```
whenever sqlerror exit rollback

insert into test values (100);
insert into test values ('A');
```

Calling it:

```
M:\>sqlplus scott/tiger@orcl @p.sql

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on ╚et Ruj 26 13:38:50 2019

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Real Application Clusters, Automatic Storage Management, OLAP,
Data Mining and Real Application Testing options


1 row created.

insert into test values ('A')
                         *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01722: invalid number


Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Real Application Clusters, Automatic Storage Management, OLAP,
Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

M:\>
```

Result:

```
SQL> select * From test;

no rows selected

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks for the support. but I need to execute multiple scripts in that calling script.sql.

Answer (score 0):

You can rollback the actions from called scripts, but in addition to WHENEVER command you must also SET AUTOCOMMIT OFF.  Normally when Sqlplus exits a script invoked in a separate file it commits. However the preceding overrides that action. See below: (save each script to the indicated file.)

```
   ----------------------------------------------------------------------------           -- script mst_0.sql
    create table multi_script_test( id integer, description varchar2(50));
    insert into multi_script_test values( 0, 'Initial before script.');
    commit;

    -- script mst_1.sql
    insert into multi_script_test values( 1, 'Insert from script mst_1');

    -- script mst_2.sql
    insert into multi_script_test values ( 2, 'Insert from script mst_2');

    -- script mst_3.sql
    insert into multi_script_test values ( 3/0, 'oops');

    -- script mst_4.sql
    insert into multi_script_test values ( 4, 'Insert from script mst_4');

    -- main script mst_main.sql
    set echo on
    set autocommit off
    whenever sqlerror continue rollback

    @@c:/so/ora/mst_0.sql
    @@c:/so/ora/mst_1.sql
    @@c:/so/ora/mst_2.sql
    -- following should display rows 0, 1, 2
    select * from multi_script_test;

    -- generate error and due to whenever directive 'rollback' discard rows 1,2
    @c:/so/ora/mst_3.sql

    -- continue script processing, also due to whenever directive 'contunue'
    @c:/so/ora/mst_4.sql
    commit;
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

    sqlplus -- complete the signon 

    -- run main script 
    @mst_main


    -- following show show display 0, 4
    select * from multi_script_test;

    exit
```